# Python: detecting unicode

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am using Python's `re` module to censor some text. I have to censor both ASCII and Unicode text, so I need to set `re`'s Unicode flag if the text is Unicode. Is there a way that I can detect whether the text is Unicode or not?

Comment: Just set Unicode flag on all the time.

Comment: How come you're getting a mix? Your framework should *only* be dealing with `unicode`s.

Comment: I need to escape special characters in my text, so the character '\' is escape if I turn it into unicode. that's why I need a way to find out which type of encoding it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is a subset of Unicode, you don't have to do anything -- unless you have reasons to suspect your text is neither ASCII not Unicode (eg Windows CP 1252 et altri), just go with Unicode by defaut.

Comment: I need to escape special characters in my text, so the character '\' is escape if I turn it into unicode. that's why I need a way to find out which type of encoding it is.

Comment: Encoding a text as Unicode doesn't magically escape characters. 'dda' is correct, just use Unicode strings everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
 isinstance( s, unicode)
```

to see if the object is unicode. But if you have all your strings as *encoded* unicode, then you need to know the encoding. For email-processing applications that can be a nightmare. In the past, I have used [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to that end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `text.decode('utf-8')` and if it succeeds without error, the text is UTF-8 encoded Unicode (of which pure ASCII is a subset). If it's anything else, i.e. a code page, it will probably raise an exception.